# sokect client data handling in node patterns

Tags: node.js, sockets, events

So i'm building an vscode extension in typescript and node and i have a python app which sends data with socket to localhost 8080 and im catching it like this :

```
export default async function getSock(port, adress, dataOld): Promise<void> { 


let server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding('binary');

    socket.on('data', async function (data) {
        console.log('client send:' + data);
        let m = port
        new **UI**(data);
        server.close()
    });
    
    socket.on('error', function (exception) {
        console.log('socket error:' + exception);
        socket.end();

    });

    socket.on('close', function (data) {
        console.log('client close:' + data);

    });

    socket.on('end', function() { 
        console.log('disconnected from server');
        server.close()

     });
     
})

server.listen({port: port, adress: adress});
}
```

Now i need some mechanism that if listening for 5 seconds and no data passed from the socket, i stop listening and call "new **UI**(dataOld)"

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say "but when I don't have the data in the socket"?  How does that occur?  How would you know when to stop waiting for actual data to arrive and to instead use `dataOld`?

Comment: Also, it is dangerous to assume that one packet of incoming `data` event is a full set of data.  TCP in nodejs is a stream and data can arrive in any sorts of pieces.  Instead, you have to know your own protocol and make sure that you have a full piece of data that you can process.

Comment: the first comment is what i try to answer, what kind of pattern would be appropriate to know is the stream has the data ready, and if not to emit event that serves old data


i assume it could be a timer if not data on the listener for 5 seconds, activate new UI(dataOld)

Comment: so is it possible to stop listening the server after 10 seconds of listenting and call the class with dataOld ?